# Parse Background Job Not Saving Objects

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Okay I'm trying to set these objects in the user class, but for some reason it's not saving. It's very straight forward, or it seems like it should be:

This gets user:

```
var actionCompleted = results[i].get("ActionComplete");
var user = results[i].get("User");
```

This Gets Objects:

```
 var moneyLost = user.get("MoneyLost");
 var daysRow = user.get("DaysInRow");
 var daysWoken = user.get("DaysWoken");
 var daysLate = user.get("DaysLate");
```

This Sets and Saves The Objects:

```
 user.set = ("MoneyLost", moneyLost + bountyVal);
     user.set = ("DaysInRow", daysRow++);
     user.set = ("DaysWoken", daysWoken++);
     user.save(user, {
      success: function(gameScore) {
       // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
       alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);
      },
      error: function(gameScore, error) {
       // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
       // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
       alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
      }
     });
```

And This Sets and Saves More Objects:

```
user.set = ("DaysInRow",0);
    user.set = ("DaysLate", daysLate++);
     user.save(user, {
      success: function(gameScore) {
       // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
       alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);
      },
      error: function(gameScore, error) {
       // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
       // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
       alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
      }
     });
```

Comment: `userObject.set('fieldname', value)`

Comment: @eth3lbert I tried this I was unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off and you need to do pre-increment rather than post.

```
var actionCompleted = results[i].get("ActionComplete");
var user = results[i].get("User"); 

var moneyLost = user.get("MoneyLost");
var daysRow = user.get("DaysInRow");
var daysWoken = user.get("DaysWoken");
var daysLate = user.get("DaysLate");

user.set("MoneyLost", moneyLost + bountyVal);
user.set("DaysInRow", ++daysRow);
user.set("DaysWoken", ++daysWoken);
user.save(null, {
    success: function(gameScore) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);
    },
    error: function(gameScore, error) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
    }
});

user.set("DaysInRow", 0);
user.set("DaysLate", ++daysLate);
user.save(null, {
    success: function(gameScore) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);
    },
    error: function(gameScore, error) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried the code you provided but I was unable to get the objects to save.

Comment: Which alerts are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any of them.

Comment: Did you include the Parse Js SDK?

Comment: I think so, how can I tell?